# how to wait for data then print all at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so im using WMI and Open Hardware Monitor to get my CPU and GPU temperatures.

the code

`import wmi`

`w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
temperature_infos = w.Sensor()
for sensor in temperature_infos:
    if sensor.SensorType==u'Temperature':
        print(sensor.Name)
        print(sensor.Value)`

how would i make it so it waits for `sensor.Name` and `sensor.Value` and then prints it all at once, instead of printing it as it gets the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import wmi

w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
temperature_infos = w.Sensor()
d = dict()  ## Create an empty dictionary

for sensor in temperature_infos:
    if sensor.SensorType==u'Temperature':
        #print(sensor.Name)
        #print(sensor.Value)
        d[sensor.Name] = sensor.Value

print(d)  # Print the dictionary when the loop is over
```